# during installation of Subversive Connector Discovery - 'problems occurred'

Tags: eclipse, svn

I'm trying to install SVN client on Eclipse Helios,
I've installed all SVN modules from Collaboration node (in updates),
now after restart I can choose a connector
'Subversive Connector Discovery' form appears.
but whatever i choose and press 'finish', i've got
'Problems occurred, while performing operation: Operation Details
See error log for details'

What happened? where is the log for this operation ?

Comment: Please don't forget to mark an accepted answer so others no right away that this question was solved. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found log in

!ENTRY org.eclipse.team.svn.core.svnnature 4 0 2010-12-14 23:58:47.156
(...)
Contains: Missing requirement: SVNKit 1.3.3 Implementation (Optional) 2.2.2.I20101203-1700 (org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.svnkit16.feature.group 2.2.2.I20101203-1700) requires 'org.eclipse.team.svn.feature.group [0.7.9.I20101001-1700,1.0.0)' but it could not be found

I've updated this component (from incubation branch in updating service (that's why it wasn't updated automatically).
then, eclipse stopped working (it just won't start, i had to update jdk from 1.6.0_17 to 1.6.0_21
and now everything is working ;)

Answer (score 29):

I found that the version tied with the Helios release broke with the December 3rd release of the connectors that are separately released due to licensing.  If you turn on the Early Access update site in your "available software sites", it should update the main Subversive to at least 0.7.9.I20101203-1700 which will solve the problems.

If you want to manually add the update site, the URL for http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/0.7/update-site/

**It should already be in your site list but disabled.**  Just enable it, run an update and update the main subversive package and connectors package.  Upon restart, you should be able to update the JavaHL and/or SVNkit component.

Comment: ditto. after struggling with various eclipse versions on Win7 64, with subclipse, and subversive, problems coinciding with the ADT plugin, finally finding your answer got me running. Merry Xmas! :-)

Comment: There's also now a FAQ on the download page (not on the FAQ page though...) http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/downloads.php#faq

Comment: If you make a mistake, to get the 'Subversive Connector Discovery' dialog again you need to uninstall the connector it will be listed as 'Native ...' or 'SVN Kit ..' this will then prompt to install a connector on the next use of subversive.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than try to figure out why Subversive and its 2-step installation process doesn't work, I recommend just using [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/). It's simpler to setup and provides the same functionality.

If you are attached to using Subversive, since its connectory discovery is clearly not working - just add the polarion update site ([details here](http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/subversive/download.php?utm_source=eclipse.org&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=subversive)) for the svn connectors and install them that way.

Answer (score 1):

As Aaron in #2 suggested you have to update the subversive plugin.

I tried to

> If you want to manually add the update site, the URL for http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/0.7/update-site/

but eclipse complained that this was a duplicate of a site. So I checked the Available Sites and way down in the list I found the entry -> put a tick in the box and enable it.

Afterwards click on Check for Updates and it will find an updated version of the subversive plugin. Update and afterwards you should be able to install the new svn connectors. (The new screen only presented about 4 connectors compared to the usual 8-10 I saw in earlier versions)

That's how I could solve the problem with the connector not installing.

Answer (score 0):

this link http://www.dingobytes.com/tutorial/subversion-install-for-eclipse-helios-3-6 
has the ultimate answer.

in brief:

> In order to resolve this you need to enable a subversive repository. Go to Help > Install New Software and then click the “Available Software Sites” link. In the window, you will get a list of available software. Scrolldown the list and look for http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/0.7/update-site/. Select it and then click the ‘Enable’ button and the click ‘OK’.

PLEASE NOTE: enable the site, not simply add it!!!