# How to fix Subclipse if I can't share my project anymore?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I use *Eclipse* for programming and *SVN* for versioning.
Since not long, I can't share my project. I have this error after click on *myproject* -> *Team* -> *Share* -> *SVN*:

> Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot be loaded.

When I look at the SVN, I have this message :

> Could not create the view:
>   org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.repository.RepositoriesView

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: You need to reinstall Subclipse to your Eclipse.  Worst case, you'll need to unpack Eclipse to a different directory and reinstall Subclipse.

Comment: If it were just the svn connector library not found i'd suggest you switch to another svn connector (if possible) or add the update site for connectors (this was the case in the past in a somewhat related way - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445095/during-installation-of-subversive-connector-discovery-problems-occurred). But it seems your problem is deeper, so yes - reinstall or maybe update Subclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found, I redownload Eclipse and unpack it and I reinstall subversion in Eclipse and now it's work.

Answer (score 8):

Are you using Subversive or Subclipse?

I had the same problem with the first one, uninstalled it, installed Subclipse and that was it!

Here is the 
[link](http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA)

Comment: All good now after getting rid of subversive and then installing subeclipse

Answer (score -1):

**Subversive. Connect with Native JavaHL 1.8.13.**

**Subclipse** did **NOT** work for me as I downloaded from Eclipse Marketplace.